# SSIS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have created ssis package which import data from a .csv file into sql server table.

It is working fine but now i want to give condition that package should only run when date and time is changed or csv file is modified (Or new csv comes in)

Comment: And... the problem is... ?

Comment: Date and time of what is changed?

Comment: Now the issue is I want my pacakge to do import process only when the csv is modified or when new records are added that csv.

Comment: When data time of csv file is changed. @Cool_Br33ze

Comment: You could create an infinite loop package but SSIS packages can be resource intensive if left to run forever.

I would consider creating an Agent job that runs every X seconds/mins that checks for changes in the file and if there is a change to execute the package.

Comment: You could try a script task that looks at the file system's info on the CSV file. You coudl count the rows in the csv file as a first step. you coudl check the data against ids already held in your sql server table. this is not a code problem as such, its more that you are looking to learn SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that on your SSIS, you can create a script task who check if date and time is changed or csv file is modified.

see this doc : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/script-task

Or i think you can create an SQL Agent who check this every X time. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent